# Twitter showing a placeholder image if no image is given on web page

Tags: twitter, share, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, twitter-card

I am sharing a url http://www.aao.org/eye-on-advocacy-article/key-congressional-committee-opposes-part-b-demo on twitter which do not have any `og:image` meta tag as there is no image present for this article.

But when sharing the url on twitter, it takes a default placeholder image which is actually a twitter image https://ton.twimg.com/tfw/assets/link_v1_e64f66f5650df987d97cc5f00c4cb5987f367028.svg is shown with the shared link but it should display no image at all.
[image: Current result when sharing on twitter]

The twitter meta tags I am using for this page are:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="American Academy of Ophthalmology">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Key Congressional Committee Echoes Academy’s Opposition to Medicare’s Proposed Part B Drug Demonstration">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Our friends in Congress are pressuring CMS to change planned initiative that would hurt our ability to care for ophthalmology’s patients">
<meta name="twitter:creator">

and some other og meta tags
```

Can anyone suggest what I can add or remove in the page so there is no placeholder image show when sharing on twitter?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter doesn't allow an article to not have a thumbnail, so you need to add a thumbnail to remove the default thumbnail.

Try this:

```html
<meta
    name="twitter:image"
    content="image url here"
  />

// If the above doesn't work

<meta
    name="og:image"
    content="image url here"
  />
```

You can also set the image to be a blank image (white background or totally transparent) if you want